# Kibana is not responding but cluster is working fine

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, aws-elasticsearch

We are using the Kibana hosted endpoint that comes with Elasticsearch on AWS accessible with a URL like https://*******.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/

As of a few days ago, Kibana became unaccessible and Chrome/cURL returns a ERR_TIMED_OUT error.

Telnet shows that the port 443 is timing out:

```
telnet ******.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com 443
Trying 10.0.1.238...
telnet: connect to address 10.0.1.238: Operation timed out
Trying 10.0.0.28...
telnet: connect to address 10.0.0.28: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Everything else on the cluster seems to be working fine. Accessing Elastic thru code works and the cluster status is "Status: Green". The "Cluster Health" page on AWS does not show any visible issues.

The only other issue I am aware of is our inability to migrate Elastic from 6.x to 7.x due to this error:

```
Checking upgrade eligibility - Failed
Cluster has 3082.0 shards per node which exceeds the setting cluster.max_shards_per_node value 1000
```

According to AWS documentation "The 7.x versions of Elasticsearch have a default setting of no more than 1,000 shards per node" so I am unsure if this is related to our inability to access Kibana or not.

Would anyone know of a good next step to re-gain access to Kibana?

Comment: That's a private IP. Were you connected to a VPN when it was working before but not now?

Comment: I am using an SSH tunnel to connect to Kibana so that telnet example is on the same LAN. It used to work previously so I don't think that the tunnel is the issue.

Comment: you should set public   ip  bind to kibana and elasticsearch